Opamp and regulator not behaving the same on breadboard vs SPICE simulations
I am designing a circuit which is intended to map a signal in the 0-5V range to the 1.75-7.0V range. To do this I am using an LM317T voltage regulator in conjunction with a TLC2272 Rail-to-Rail opamp. The issue I'm having is that my breadboarded circuit with these components does not behave the same as my LtSpice simulations. For example, in my sim, the range maps correctly as seen below when I apply a 2.5V sin wave to the input:

However, since I'm still just prototyping I am not testing this circuit with an AC source yet, instead I just want to confirm that there is 1.76V on the output when there is 0V on the input like so:

As you can see, this also works as expected in the simulation. However when I measure the same voltages in my breadboarded circuit I read 7.5V on the output instead of the 1.76V. I tested the voltage regulator section of the circuit in isolation and get ~1.75V but when I connect the two circuits together it no longer works properly.
So why exactly does my circuit stray so much from the simulations when put together? What design patterns can be followed to avoid this deviation in future designs?
Edit: Pictures of the actual circuit



Post a couple of photos of the breadboard so we can check the connections.

I was going to write a comment but it got too long, so I put an answer instead.  As @Transistor wrote, share photos. To which I add check your work.  Share your sim and we can run it ourselves.

@Transistor Added some pictures

@JayM How would I share a sim? I wasn't aware I could add attachments here.

Nobody knows except you what nodes are n007 and n006, so please label the nodes you are plotting so we don't have to guess. Please use the standard op-amp symbol in future, not a square box, so that we can see at a glance what you've built. Lastly, spread the components out, your schematic is a condensed mess.

R3 in your schematic says it’s 1K, but on your breadboard it’s 39ohm (unless the colors aren’t coming out right in the photo).

Where are all the decoupling capacitors? They are not optional.

@SimonFitch Thanks for the feedback. n007 and n006 are measuring the same thing which is the labeled Vout in the sim.

@Transistor I originally didn't include them because my application is not strictly AC and is closer to DC than AC. The goal was to translate a specific MAF sensor's voltage range into another sensor's voltage range. Are decoupling capacitors needed in every application even if the signal is not perpetually oscillating?

@SteKulov Good catch! I missed that one. However issue persists still after that change. I checked the rest of the values as well.

@JaysonOkhman, the decoupling capacitors are to prevent oscillation and form a local short-term low-impedance voltage stabilisation to counter any problems caused by inductance of wiring or PCB tracks. This can be a problem on the voltage regulator and on the op-amp. You probably won't detect it using a multimeter but should see it on a 'scope.

Simple tests: Separate the LM317 and OpAmp.  Instead of measuring the final output, measure the linear regulator first.  Check your component values.  It is easy to misread resistor colours.
My calculation (from the LM317 Datasheet) says it should be between 4.375 and 4.675.
The first thing to learn with Opamp devices is that the manufacturers can't lie on the datasheet front page (though mistakes happen), but they can fail to mention things that are less than great attributes. The marketing department have as much influence over the content as the engineers. Manufacturers regularly bury bad news in the tables or graphs.
Lesson 1: Always read the datasheet fully and pay special attention to the parameter tables.
Some observations:

The LM317 is a very old device, it has a very high feedback input leakage current.  You can't use it with larger resistors values, so in low power systems the divider is wasteful.  That current varies with temperature, so makes the output inaccurate.
Not sure what your design intent is.  But take a look at adjustable precision bandgap references, they would achieve the same with less components.  The current into the opamp is almost zero, it does not need a voltage regulator.

To My Answer:
I am answering this as it contains a few good lessons in practical electronics.
An opamp works using a servo mechanism.  It adjust the output to bring the error (the difference between the input pins) to zero.  A working opamp circuit always has (almost) zero (i.e. just a few micro volts) between the input pins.
Though the difference is zero, the actual potential relative to the devices GND pin (or sometimes the output pin) may have limitations. This is called the common mode input voltage range (Vcm).
A note on RRIO Opamps.
Early so called 'Rail to Rail Input/Output' may have a rail to rail output, or even a rail to rail input, but not necessarily a rail to rail common mode range.  Indeed some are not even truly rail to rail, often the voltage depends on the output current, or the input current rises rapidly.
Another lesson in electronics :)
I think that is the case here. Referencing the datasheet for the TLC2272 From table 6.5, What they call the value Vicr (The maximum Vcm) is 3.5V with 2.5V typical. You are applying ~4.5V/2 = 2.25V. So the device input is close to or out of spec.
We find things like this the hard way, indeed it's what makes electronics interesting. A key take away: RRIO is a compromise.
Indeed some RR/RRI/RRO/RRIO opamps do really weird things as the signals meet the rails, so often the advice is that mostly (and though the marketing department would have you think otherwise), stretching the spec never works and it's better practice to always leave a gap if you can.  If you can't test it fully (i.e. not just simulate).
How to prove this?
Just go through the product selectors and seek a better opamp for your purpose, and/or change the circuit to avoid limits.  There are opamps out there that are almost perfect these days (though they are not cheap).
Luckily many opamps share the same footprint, but be careful as some have the rails swapped.
If the above is correct is LTSpice broken, I hear you say?
Last lesson: Think how spice works.
It's not magic!  Somebody had to code the model for every component.  Some components are modelled amazingly accurately others are just a sort of nod to the vague behaviour of the device, or based on a stack of 'ideal' components and, sadly, ideal components fail to exist.
There are always errors, tolerances, environmental effects, limits and even latent bugs to consider.  Also (as could be the case here) it is rare to find the model includes accurate behaviour if the component is used out of spec.  I've been known to laugh out loud when my simulated opamp produces an output that is bigger than the PSU rail.
If you want an accurate simulation from LTSpice, one that reflects real life as close as possible, stick to Analog Devices or Linear Technology parts.  LT is now owned by AD since 2017 and AD have worked hard to port their models to LTSpice. As LT wrote LTSpice (in fact, mostly one guy) they have access to the internal workings of their devices (and now ADs), so can supply models that are far more accurate (or as accurate as they wish may be a better phrase) than any generic part. Indeed this is why you can simulate a high speed switch mode PSU in LTSpice, because the models are 'special'.
The same is true for simulators from other vendors such as (no defunct TINA from Texas Instrument, TI) - TI have replaced TINA with a cut down SiMetrix (which is amazing but sadly very hobbled unless you pay for it) If you are using a TI device, consider using the model for it in the simulator it was written for.  Some SPICE models are portable, others are not.  SiMetrix is very different and much faster than SPICE, but lacks a wide range of models.  Some manufacturers make models for their devices but use the base model cards (they used to be punch cards) from LT, so some are accurate.
Even then it is not unusual for a great idea 'proved' in SPICE simulation to be rubbish on the bench.  Never the less its always good to try it and learn why...

Thanks for your response. A lot of helpful points here. However I would like to disagree with you on a couple things. Firstly, I mentioned that I did test the LM317 by itself. This works pretty well with the voltage coming out to ~1.78V. I am not sure how you came up with the 4.375V value. This is partly the source of my confusion. It seems something is off with the combination of the Opamp and the LM317, but not with the components themselves. Secondly, I do not understand how I am using the TLC2272 out of spec, what do you mean by the ~2.25V at the input?

@Jayson * The regulator needs a certain load currrent (typ. 3.5mA) to maintain regulation. Try dropping the feedback resistors for the regulator to 1/10th of the original value.

@Raonoke Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it and the results look better but still off. I am now getting 3.62V on the output. What's interesting is in the sim, If instead of connecting R3 to ground I leave it open, I also get 3.62V. Any idea why my actual circuit is behaving like R3 is open instead of at 0V?

@Jayson * With R3 gounded the amplifier has a gain of 1, without R3 a gain of 2. Check if R3 is really  gounded on the breadboard. Test only the amplifier stage by connecting an external, known voltage (e.g. 1.5V battery or similar) to R4+R7.

@Raonoke, Your comment about the regulator feedback resistors solved my problem. Feel free to post an answer if you wish.

@Jayson * No need for an extra answer for such a minor problem.
